# How to expire previous session on a concurrent session access

Tags: spring, grails

Iam using spring security in my grails application. I need to expire the previous session while login with the same username on a different browser. Does concurrent session limiting will help this? How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to expire the previous session while login with the same
>   username on a different browser. Does concurrent session limiting will
>   help this?

Yes, concurrent session will be best case for you in this regard.

> How to do this ?

Create your own class(under /src/groovy/) for handling the concurrent sessions by extending the `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` class like below

```
import com.constants.CodeConstants
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy

/**
 * Overrides the default "ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy"
 * for limiting the maximum allowed session per user role
 */
class MyConcurrentSessionControlStrategy extends ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy{

    MyConcurrentSessionControlStrategy(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        super(sessionRegistry)
    }

    /**
     * Check if role is "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN" then set allowed session to 1
     * else unlimited (i.e. -1)
     *
     * @param authentication
     *
     * @return : maximum allowed sessions
     */
    protected int getMaximumSessionsForThisUser(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication authentication) {

        Long maximumSession = -1

        if (CodeConstants.ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN in authentication.authorities*.authority) {
            maximumSession = 1
        }

        return maximumSession;
    }
}
```

In my case I have limited only super admin users to have only one session, you can have multiple role users.

And register our implementation bean under the `resources.groovy` like below

```
import com.security.MyConcurrentSessionControlStrategy
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl
import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter

   /**
     * For handling the concurrent session control
     * exceptionIfMaximumExceeded = false -> invalidates the previous session
     * exceptionIfMaximumExceeded = true -> invalidates the new session
     */
    sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)

    concurrencyFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter) {
        sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
        logoutHandlers = [ref("rememberMeServices"), ref("securityContextLogoutHandler")]
        expiredUrl = '/login/auth'
    }

    concurrentSessionControlStrategy(MyConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) {
        alwaysCreateSession = true
        exceptionIfMaximumExceeded = false
        maximumSessions = -1
    }
```

> Note : The above code has been tested and working as expected in
>   `Grails version 2.4.4`  and spring security
>   `spring-security-core:2.0.0` plugin

Comment: This answer was so helpful. Thanks a lot Prakash Thete